# error at customer registration cart software

Tags: php, json, opencart

1. if affiliate code is missed out (not entered). it doesnt gives an error like it does for email or lastname. line 148. I just added for affiliate_code as was for email or lastname etc

cart.open-pages.com may be visited , purchase , checkout, register.

.2 I am having errors because of line 157 to 160 
can anyone tell if the the code is ok in  http://pastebin.ca/2331831 . 
its giving an internal server error

additional related file 
http://pastebin.ca/2331818
thats in view>theme>default>template>checkout>register.tpl

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should really have the code that's giving problems on site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're reading `affiliate_code` and not checking if it is empty. You should use the [empty](http://php.net/empty) function before passing it to the query.

```
if( ! empty($_POST['affiliate_code']))
{
    // your affiliate code here
}
```

Comment: I have already set that check on 148, thats what not working, why its not giving an error if user doesnt fills the field and it does gives error for email, firstname etc?